# How to modify Django template variable with JS and return it changes on it

Tags: javascript, django

I would like to pass a list of ids to a view when i click on a link:

```
<a href="{% url 'app:manage_ids' %}?ids={{ids}}">
```

So i have created a template var and pass it to js:

```
{% with ids="" %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.ids = "{{ ids }}";
  </script>
{% endwith %}
```

I manage object ids when click on checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="{{ object.id }}">
```

Adding or removing it to a list:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();

  // if django template var is empty
  var list_ids = [];
  // else
  var list_ids = window.ids;

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    list_ids.push(id);
      // here i have to save it on a django template var to use it on the click link
  }
  else {
    const index = list_ids.indexOf(id);
    if (index > -1) {
      list_ids.splice(index, 1);
      // here i have to save it on a django template var to use it on the click link 
    }
  }
});
```

Anybody could help me about how to do it ?
Thanks you so much.

Comment: Where is the code for the trigger action here? Finally when do you want to pass it view and how?

Comment: @MohitC updated with trigger action.

Comment: what is the relevance of variable `window.ids`?

Comment: pass js list of ids to django template variable

Comment: Why? You want to recieve the ids in view of link you will click right?

Comment: yes, i want get the list of ids on the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant update the django variable and expect it to update your `href` value of the link.

Moreover, you should not send the value of a GET query parameter as a list datastructure, instead you'll send it as `?ids=<value1>&ids=<value2>`

To do this you'll have to first construct such string of url and then dynamically update the href of your hyperlink with it.

You can first decalre the string variable for you href in javascript somehwere as:

```
var id_link = "{% url 'app:manage_ids' %}?ids=";
```

Then whenever the click checkbox function is called you can add new value to this and update the href of link:

```
id_link += "&ids=" + id;
```

Add an id to your href and get it and update it

```
var a = document.getElementById('yourlinkId');
a.href = id_link
```

Now when someone clicks this link, you can get these in query parmeters in view as:

```
request.GET.getlist('ids')
```

and you shall get list of all IDs.

---

**Note** (My two cents): Ideally in a good archiecture this should happen by clicking a button with a post request from template in django.